# Manually resolving jQuery deferreds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

I think the question title is not exactly what I want, but it's a bit complicated to summarise. I will attempt to explain:

I am working on an interface that requires the user to log in, and the login token expires after a set period of time, and it performs operations via ajax. The end result is that a user can be logged out because their token expired, and they then try to perform an ajax request, which doesn't work because they're not logged in.

This is how I've tried to combat it:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, jqXHR, options) {
  if (jqXHR.status == 403) {
    doLogin(function() {
      $.ajax(options);
    });
  }
});
```

Assume the doLogin logs the user in and then calls the callback. The second call to $.ajax retries the ajax request (now that the user is logged in) and it will hopefully succeed.

Now, here's the tricky part -- it works if using the callback mechanism provided by jQuery, but not using deferreds. So this works:

```
$.get('/something', function() {
  // got it!
});
```

and this works:

```
$.ajax('/something', {
  success: function() {
    // got it!
  }
});
```

but this does not:

```
$.get('/something').done(function() {
  // got it!
});
```

Any ideas how i can accomplish this?

Comment: Nope. Since you aren't passing a function to the options, doLogin has no way of figuring out what success callback should be called. There is no workaround for this other than not using the .done method. You could build your own promise, but that would require still using the success option, thus defeating the purpose.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The documentation for $,get has some notes regarding versions and promises, verify that first https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: You should be doing `.then(null, function() { return doLogin().then(retry); })`

Comment: @spojam I'm currently using 1.11.3.